# CURL hangs after form submission

Tags: php, curl

I have searched for a while and found many similar situations occurring for others; however, I cannot find a solution that works for me.

I have the latest Ubuntu, Apache, and PHP versions running on my server.  I checked for updates and after installing them, nothing improved.  Here is my code:

```
$ip = getServerIP($stand).":8080";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'server-id: '.$stand,
  'script: '.$script,
  'device: '.$device,
  'api-key: '.file_get_contents(getcwd() .'/../secure/serverkey')
    ));

curl_exec($ch)
curl_close($ch);
```

`$stand` is a parameter the parent function takes.  Everything works fine up until I call `curl_exec`.  This code runs when a form has been submitted.  Chrome hangs on the form page for about 2 minutes, and then it finally goes to the page this code is on.  Any guidance?

Update: The problem was on the C# side; this question is no longer relevant.  Sorry, I am working with someone else and they are handling the C#, so I don't know what the issue was.

Comment: @cale_b This is not chrome specific; I have tested it on Edge.  Edge says it's "waiting..."  This IS the page the code is on.  "This code runs when a form has been submitted" means that this is on the page AFTER the form.  This code is exactly where it hangs.  Calm down with the downvotes.

Comment: @cale_b I have tested the code many times with logging statements to verify where it hangs.  Using `echo` wouldn't work because of the page not loading for 2 minutes.

Comment: dit you 1. try from command line from the server try to issue this curl (see if it is a com issue) 2. try with verbose curl to get some detail about the connexion, 3. calm yourself about downvotes on an unclear question ?

Comment: The server does not respond.  It's C# code.  All it needs to do is receive @cale_b.  Sorry, I guess I could've said "The Browser" if that suits you better.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I can try from command line, but I know the server it's targeting can receive these packets, it just takes a **long** time.  It's not a comms issue, most likely.  I can try verbose CURl.

Comment: @KarseyRenfert comms is about 1. egress, 2. travel, and 3. ingress. You might be surprised. Finally, do you have xdebug in there ? if yes, nuke it to do a meaningful try.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I am trying to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` but I cannot find the logs; the correct ones for this dont seem to be under /var/log/apache2, unless I am missing something.  Wireshark is showing that the packet is being CURl'd the second I hit the button, so idk where the hangup is.  What is xdebug?  In where?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @cale_b I am sorry you feel this way, but I fail to see any suggestions you have made that I either haven't tried (like verbose CURl), or that are relevant (as far as I can tell, you've given up on explaining I guess??)  Update: Now you've deleted your comments.  That is VERY helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @cale_b Hey, thanks for deleting comments.  Wonderfully helpful of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too bulky for comments, so here is I setup verbose CURL in my ApiHelper class:

```
$st       = microtime(true);
$verbiage = null;
if ($this->verbose) {
    // write out the curl debug stuff
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT , false);
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
    $verbiage = fopen('php://temp' , 'w+');
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_STDERR , $verbiage);
}

$resp  = curl_exec($ch);
$end   = microtime(true);           // get as float
$delta = 1000.0 * ($end - $st);    // treat as float
if (Config::getCurrentConfig()->options->logServerResponseTimes) {
    $this->getInstanceLogger()->debug("WS Round trip took " . sprintf("%.2f" , $delta) . " ms.");
}
if ($this->verbose) {
    // rewind and log the verbose output
    rewind($verbiage);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbiage);
    $this->getInstanceLogger()->debug("Verbose cURL : \n$verboseLog");
    fclose($verbiage);
}

curl_close($ch);
return $resp;
```

Finally, xdebug is the protocol suite in support of symbolic debugging of php processes.  It slows down things some, but mostly tries to initiate outbound connexions all the time between the running (under debug) php process and a listening process.  Look in your php.ini files (apache, php-fpm, and cli), and turn off xdebug if it is there.

Comment: I'll check it out.  This looks very helpful; thanks :)